# Inserting a string in the middle of another string

Tags: c, string, file, filesystems

i have a binary file organizedlike that

- the file is devided to blocks
- each block is a fixed length string
- the block conatains ordred and variabel length data
- `lien` is somthing related to another task so we dont need it for that

  ```
  typedef struct Tbloc
  {
      char tab[MAX];
      int lien;

  } Tbloc;


  typedef struct Tbloc Buffer;   //BUFFER


  typedef struct TOVC
  {
      FILE *fichier;

  } TOVC;
  ```

  i have functions that get a block number i and put it in buffer

  ```
  void LireDir(TOVC *f, int i, Buffer *buf);
  ```

  and also a function that write the buffer in the file in the position i

  ```
  void EcrireDir(TOVC *f, int i, Buffer buf);
  ```

  i want to inert "0000000000" in the first block in the pos = 0

  i have several problems with my functions i used and i dont know the reason

  my code is

  ```
  void deviser (char *enrg, char *enrg1, char *enrg2 , int i){
      int j;
      for(j = 0 ;j< i ;j++){
          enrg1[j] = enrg[j];
      }
      enrg1[j] = '\0';
      for(j = i ;j< strlen(enrg) ;j++){
          enrg2[j-i] = enrg[j];
      }
      enrg2[j-i] = '\0';
  }

  char*  extraire_chain(char *chaine ,int j ){
      int i;
      // char *chaine = "123456789";
      char *chaine2;
      chaine2 = (char*)malloc((strlen(chaine)-j)*sizeof(char));
      for(i = j ;i< strlen(chaine) ;i++){
          chaine2[i-j] = chaine[i];
      }
      chaine2[i-j] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n",chaine2);
      return chaine2;
  }
  // insert chaine2 in chaine1 in the position j
  char* inserer_chain(char *chaine1 ,char *chaine2 ,int j ){
      int i;
      char *chaine3;
      chaine3 = (char*)malloc((strlen(chaine1)+strlen(chaine2))*sizeof(char));
      for(i = 0 ;i< j ;i++){
          chaine3[i] = chaine1[i];
      }
      chaine3[i] = '\0';
      strcat(chaine3,chaine2);
      strcat(chaine3,extraire_chain(chaine1,j));
      return chaine3;
  }




  //=======================================================================================
  void insersion(TOVC *f,TOVC *f1,char* chaine,int i ,int position){
      char* s1,*s2;
      char* ch1,*ch2,*ch11,*ch22;
      Buffer buf, buf2;

          LireDir(f,i,&buf);
          s1=extraire_chain(buf.tab,position);
          sprintf(s1,"%s%s",chaine,s1);
          deviser(s1,ch1,ch2,100-position);
          strcpy(buf.tab,inserer_chain(buf.tab,ch1,position));

          if (buf.lien == -1){

              ALLOC_BLOC(f1);
              int i1 = entete(f1,1);
              buf.lien = i1;
              EcrireDir(f,i,buf);
              LireDir(f1,i1,&buf2);
              strcpy(buf2.tab,ch2);
              EcrireDir(f1,i1,buf2);
              FERMER(f1);
          }}
  ```

when debugging i have the problems in `spirntf`  i tried using strcat but i still have the same problem

i also have a problem in `deviser` and `inserer_chain` i obtain a result that does not relate to anything or it just crash

Answer (score 1):

You need make space for the inserted string. Also use the correct type for sizes and indexes.

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;
    while(*end++);

    return end - str - 1;
}

char *strinsert(char *dest, size_t pos, const char *istr)
{
    char *temp = dest, *work;
    size_t ilen = mystrlen(istr);
    size_t nmove;

    while(*temp) temp++;
    nmove = temp - dest - pos + 1;
    work = temp;
    temp += ilen;

    while(nmove--) *temp-- = *work--;
    work = dest + pos;
    while(*istr) *work++ = *istr++;

    return dest;
} 


int main()
{
    char dest[128] = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

    printf("%s", strinsert(dest, 7, "ABCD"));
}
```

Or using the standard library functions:

```
char *strinsert(char *dest, size_t pos, const char *istr)
{
    size_t ilen = strlen(istr);
    size_t dlen = strlen(dest);

    memmove(dest + pos, dest + pos + ilen, dlen - pos + 1);
    memcpy(dest + pos, istr, ilen);

    return dest;
}
```

(some parameter checks needed)

Comment: my problem is that i dont know why it does not work if i use pointers for examle         
int main()
{
    char* dest = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
    char* new = "brrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr";
    printf("%s", strinsert(dest, 7, new));
}

Comment: @ConnorRK987 because `dest` is referencing the "string literal" which cannot be modified.